# Page refresh on check/uncheck of checkbox in thymeleaf spring boot

Tags: html, spring-boot, checkbox, thymeleaf, sts

I have two checkbox on a page without any button, currently if I check/uncheck the checkbox, it automatically refresh the page and insert the values in database, but I don't want to refresh the page on check/uncheck and I want that the value should insert in database without reloading in thymeleaf.
Any solution will be helpful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: provide more detail, with these details you can use ajax.

Comment: can you explain me via example, how can I use it

Comment: If you want something to happen without page refresh, you need to use JavaScript or something like https://htmx.org/

Comment: I dont have any button on my page, only checkboxes are there, so currently I am submitting my data via checkbox click, I want to further continue with the same, but I don't want to reload my page